# AWS VPC: Reserve an external IP for VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, ip

I need to fill in a document from a customer company. They need to know an external IP address for the VPN. 
We are using AWS VPCs but I can't find the option to reserve IP addresses for later use or even to change the IP addresses on an existing VPN so I can create a dummy VPN for later usage.

Can anyone help me with that?

> #### Update 1
>
> Elastic IPs are no help here, they can only be attached to EC2 instances but creating an VPG or an VPN doesn't let you choose an EIP

---

> #### Update 2
>
> It seems that there are no options for doing this easily. A Solution I could think of are creating an ec2 instance as a router (with an eip accessed over internet gateway). But this seems pretty complicated. I've decided to ask the customer to change the form blueprint and allow DNS names for remote VPN endpoints.

BTW: I really don't know why this question was downvoted 2 times. It seems that people are full of troll-like mindsets instead of trying to help

Comment: Elastic IP Addresses: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-eips.html

Comment: There it says: 
> An Elastic IP address is accessed through the Internet gateway of a VPC. If you have set up a VPN connection between your VPC and your network, the VPN traffic traverses a virtual private gateway, not an Internet gateway, and therefore cannot access the Elastic IP address.

Comment: That's just saying traffic to an EC2 instance's elastic IP traverses the internet. You'd need to use the in-network private addresses for the EC2 instances if you want the traffic staying within the VPN.

Comment: I simply can't assign an eip to a VPN Connection. So where is the point in allocating one? @ceejayoz

Comment: My understanding was that you can attach an Elastic IP to the Virtual Private Gateway's Elastic Network Interfaces to give them a static external IP.

Comment: As far as I know, Elastic Network Interfaces are only attachable to ec2 instances but not to Virtual Private Gateways. You only have the option to attach a VPG to a VPC. There are no other options.

Comment: They're attachable to more than EC2 instances. https://imgur.com/bmTYuo0 "Select the instance **OR network interface** to which you want to associate this Elastic IP address". My recollection is that a VPC VPN gateway gets an ENI you can tinker with.

Comment: I really appreciate your help so far, but there is one thing for sure: 
`You can create and configure network interfaces in your account and attach them to instances in your VPC.` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html

> So you can't assign, a ENI to a VPN, a VPG or any other VPC Network entity other than an EC2 Instance

Comment: ENIs are used for more than plain old EC2 instances. When I look at my list of ENIs, I see ones for ELBs, RDS instances, ElastiCache clusters etc. Fire up a gateway, attach it to your VPC, and you should see some ENIs pop up.

Comment: All services you mentioned actually have an EC2 instance underneath. VPN connections and gateways haven't. I have 2 VPG, 1 IG and 1 EC2 instance. Only the latter has led to a creation of an ENI

Comment: Download the configuration document for your AWS VPN. It shows all the settings, including IP addresses the VPN connection uses. It doesn’t change so there is no reason to have this issue. You can’t possibly be creating and changing VPN connections that often.

Comment: I think @Appleoddity has it - to get the external IP for a VPN and reserve it you set up the VPN. This means setting up a customer gateway, virtual private gateway, and probably the VPN connection. I don't think you can reserve an IP.

Comment: @Appleoddity and Tim
Thank you both for your answer. Maybe you misunderstood my problem here. I need to tell the customer networks team an IP BEFORE I know their endpoint. Without any endpoint, I can't set up a VPN connection. And if I set up a VPN connection now, I can't change the endpoint IP later. So your suggestion doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to change or influence IPs assigned to a VPN created via VPC VPN Connections. To create a VPN connection you need to configure the external endpoint right away. 
If you don't know the external endpoint and want to create a VPN to tell someone the connection details, there are 2 possible options:

1. Use DNS. (With my problem, the costumer form for VPNs didn't allow DNS)
2. Create an EC2 Instance with an Openswan server (or any other VPN software solution), make it publicly available, create a NAT Gateway, create Routes, change Security Groups ...